Multiplication in Peter-Weyl theorem
$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$It is known that the coordinate algebra $\mathcal O(\SL_n(\mathbb C))$ decomposes as direct sum of $V \otimes V^*$ for $V$ finite-dimensional irreducible representations of $\SL_n(\mathbb C)$. Is there a way to understand multiplication in $\mathcal O(\SL_n(\mathbb C))$ as an operation on $\bigoplus_{\text{$V$ irrep}} V \otimes V^*$ explicitly? For example we have $(V \otimes V^*) \otimes (W \otimes W^*) = (V \otimes W) \otimes (V \otimes W)^*$ but $V \otimes W$ is not irreducible, so I am not sure that this is relevant here.
It is enough to produce a map $V \otimes V^* \to \mathcal O(\SL_n(\mathbb C))$ for any, not necessarily irreducible, representation $V$ of $\SL_n(\mathbb C)$. The existence of such a map is claimed in the attached page of Quantum K-theoretic geometric Satake by Cautis and Kamnitzer, where it is called $r_V$ (we take $q=1$). But how to construct such a map?


You can identify $\operatorname{SL}n(\mathbb C)$ with a closed subset of $\prod{V\text{ irrep}}V^\otimes V$, this gives $\mathcal O(\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb C))$ as a quotient of the tensor product of symmetric algebras on $V\otimes V^$. No other structure is needed. The operation you have in mind shows up in the comultiplication rather than multiplication.

Let $G=\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then the action of $G$ on $V$ gives a map $G \to \operatorname{End}(V)\cong V \otimes V^$. This induces a map in the other direction $V\otimes V^\cong(V\otimes V^)^ \to \mathcal{O}(G)$. I think this is the map you want.

@DaveBenson Thank you very much! Is it possible to understand what the map $V \otimes V^* \to \mathcal O(G)$ is in terms of the decomposition of $V$ into irreducibles and $\mathcal O(G)$ as $\oplus_{V(\lambda) \ \rm irrep} V(\lambda) \otimes V(\lambda)^*$?

It's exactly the inclusion of the $\lambda$ summand.

@DaveBenson If $V=V(\lambda)$ is irreducible, then it is the inclusion of the $\lambda$ summand. What if $V$ is not irreducible? I am asking because I need to apply the map $r_V$ to tensor product of two irreducibles.

In général it's thé map taking $v \otimes \lambda $ to the function $g\mapsto \lambda(g\cdot v)$.

Whenever possible, please transcribe text rather than posting images. (It improves searchability and accessibility for people using screen readers.) If it is really necessary to post images, then please post a clean screenshot—this one is very noisy.

@Adrien Thank you very much! So this must be what is called "matrix coefficient."

As Adrien writes, $r_V $ is the matrix coefficient map.  That is what I meant when I wrote that part of the paper.  When $V $ is irreducible, yes, it is the inclusion of that direct summand.  For general $ V $, for example a tensor product of two irreps, $ r_V $ depends on the decomposition of $ V $ into irreps, which as David write below, is not so straightforward.

This is Dave Benson's comment, with more details added.
Lemma Let $G$ and $H$ be semisimple groups and let $V$ and $W$ be irreducible complex representations of $G$ and $H$ respectively. Then $V \otimes W$ is an irreducible representation of $G \times H$.
Proof Since $G$ and $H$ are semisimple, so is $G \times H$. Thus, $V \otimes W$ is semisimple if and only if ${\big(} (V \otimes W) \otimes (V \otimes W)^{\ast} {\big)}^{G \times H}$ is one dimensional. But we can rewrite this as $(V \otimes V^{\ast})^G \otimes (W \otimes W^{\ast})^H = \mathbb{C} \otimes \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}$. $\square$
Now, let $V$ be any irrep of $G$ and let $\rho : G \to \text{GL}(V)$ be the representation map. For any linear function $\lambda : \text{End}(V) \to \mathbb{C}$, the composite $\lambda \circ \rho$ is an element of $\mathcal{O}(G)$. This gives a $G \times G$ equivariant map $\text{PW}_V: \text{End}(V)^{\ast} \to \mathcal{O}(G)$. Since $V$ is irreducible as a $G$-representation, $\text{End}(V)^{\ast} \cong V^{\ast} \otimes V$ is irreducible as a $G \times G$ representation, so $\text{PW}_V$ is either $0$ or injective, and it clearly isn't zero. This is the map in Peter-Weyl.
To be much more concrete, in a way which makes it less clear that this is an equivariant map, choose a basis $e_1$, $e_2$, ..., $e_m$ for $V$. Then $\rho_V$ sends $G$ to the $m \times m$ matrices; let $\alpha^V_{ij}$ be the $(i,j)$ matrix entry of $\rho_V$. Then the functions $\alpha^V_{ij}$ are a basis for the $\text{End}(V)^{\ast}$ summand in $\mathcal{O}(G)$.

Okay, I think I understand what the OP wants now.
$\mathcal{O}(G)$ is a commutative ring, so you can ask the question:

Which map
$$\left( \bigoplus_{\lambda} V_{\lambda}^{\ast} \otimes V_{\lambda} \right) \otimes \left( \bigoplus_{\mu} V_{\mu}^{\ast} \otimes V_{\mu} \right) \longrightarrow \bigoplus_{\nu} V_{\nu}^{\ast} \otimes V_{\nu}$$
is the multiplication map $\mathcal{O}(G) \otimes \mathcal{O}(G) \to \mathcal{O}(G)$?
In other words, how do I write $\alpha^U_{i_1 i_2} \alpha^V_{j_1 j_2}$ as a linear combination of functions of the form $\alpha^W_{k_1 k_2}$?

Now, $\alpha^U_{i_1 i_2} \alpha^V_{j_1 j_2}$ is a matrix entry in the representation $U \otimes V$ of $G$. But, in order to turn this into a sum of functions of the form $\alpha^W_{k_1 k_2}$, we need to know an explicit isomorphism between $U \otimes V$ and a direct sum $\bigoplus W_k$. In other words, as the OP says in a comment, we need to be able to compute Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for $G$.

The asker specifies in a comment that they are interested in the case where $V$ is not irreducible.  That takes us to your re-phrased question (which I agree is the natural one), which is the computation of Clebsch–Gordan coefficients, right?

@LSpice So the rephrased question of David E Speyer is equivalent to the computation of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients? Do I understand correctly that explicit expressions for Clebsch-Gordan coeficients are unknown, so there is no hope to answer this question?

I thought about this a bit more after posting the answer, and I agree it comes down to Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

@DavidESpeyer It looks like this Wikipedia page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients gives an explicit formula for Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, but the formula is complicated. So can this formula be used to aswer this question?

@YellowPig, re, the tables in that article are (if I've untangled the notation correctly) only for $\operatorname{SU}(2)$.

That's for SO(3), right? And you want SL(n) (which is equivalent to SU(n)), right? So you want https://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~vondelft/Papers/ClebschGordan/ .

Your link for "Dave Benson's comment" goes to his user page.  Did you mean to link the comment?

@DavidESpeyer So for ${\rm SL}_n$ there are no explicit closed formulas for Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, right?

@LSpice Fixed, thanks! And here I was thinking "I better link that comment, before LSpice edits it in." I guess I'll leave it to you next time :).

@YellowPig Right. (As far as I know, but I do know this area reasonably well.)

Re, I gave a talk recently and, in the lunch beforehand, a graduate student was trying to remember how they knew my name.  "Oh yeah," they said, "you're the one who edits all the MathOverflow posts!"

@LSpice So the upshot is that for ${\rm SL}_2$ there is a complicated but explicit closed formula for any Clebsch-Gordan coefficient, but for ${\rm SL}_n$ there are no known explicit closed formulas for Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, right?

@LSpice Sorry, I meant to say that for ${\rm SL}_2$ there is a recursion for Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, but for $n \geq 2$ there are only algorithms to calculate Cldbsch-Gordan coefficients for ${\rm SL}_n$.

@YellowPig, re, I'm not sure I understand how one distinguishes recursion from algorithms (perhaps you meant something like "recursion versus a harder-to-implement algorithm"?), but, yes, I suspect that the situation for $\operatorname{SL}_n$ will be worse than for $\operatorname{SL}_2$.  However, I couldn't speak to the state of the art; I certainly defer to DavidESpeyer's knowledge here.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small linear category, and $F : \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Vec}$ a linear functor. The coend $\int^{\mathcal{C}} F = \int^{C \in \mathcal{C}} F(C,C)$ is by definition the cokernel:
$$\int^{\mathcal{C}} F := \mathrm{coker} \left( \bigoplus_{f : B \to C \in \mathrm{Ar}(\mathcal{C})} F(B,C) \overset{F(f,C)}{\underset{F(B,f)}{\rightrightarrows}} \bigoplus_{C \in \mathcal{C}} F(C,C) \right)$$
In other words, $\int^{\mathcal{C}}F$ is the universal vector space equipped with a dinatural map $F(C,C) \to \int^{\mathcal{C}}F$.
[Aside: Mac Lane writes $\int^{\mathcal{C}}$ for the coend, and $\int_{\mathcal{C}}$ for the end, which is just the same thing but built from kernels and products rather than from cokernels and sums. To me, these names are backwards. Indeed, a coend is a type of colimit, and colimits, to me, feel "bottom-up" in the sense that they build things additively, from generators, starting with nothing. On the other hand, ends are a type of limit, and limits to me feel "top-down": they cut away things. Oh, well.]
If $\mathcal{C}$ happens to be semisimple, then letting $\mathrm{Irr}(\mathcal{C})$ be any set of representatives one for each isomorphism class of simple objects, we have
$$ \int^{\mathcal{C}}F = \bigoplus_{C_i \in \mathrm{Irr}(\mathcal{C})} F(C_i,C_i).$$
One way to show this is to observe that semisimplicity of $\mathcal{C}$ is precisely the statement that the inclusion $\mathrm{Irr}(\mathcal{C}) \subset \mathcal{C}$ is an equivalence after Cauchy completion, and then show in general that Cauchy completion does not change the value of the coend. There are more direct proofs, of course.
The Peter–Weyl theorem does not really say that $\mathcal{O}(G) = \bigoplus_{V \in \mathrm{Irr}} V \otimes V^*$, since the RHS depends on choosing representatives of each iso class of irreps [see comments]. The Peter–Weyl theorem really says that $\mathcal{O}(G) = \int^{V \in \mathrm{Rep}(G)} V \otimes V^*$. With this statement of it, the question becomes tautologous.

I am a little confused by this answer—you say that $\int^{\mathcal C} F = \bigoplus_{C_i \in \operatorname{Irr}(\mathcal C)} F(C_i, C_i)$ and $\mathcal O(G) = \int^{V \in \operatorname{Rep}(G)} V \otimes V^$ are both true, but $\mathcal O(G) = \bigoplus_{V \in \operatorname{Irr}(V)} V \otimes V^$ is not. Surely the first equality suffers from the same objection as the last, that it depends on choosing representatives for the isomorphism classes? …

… I am used to seeing the Peter–Weyl theorem as the statement that, for every irreducible $V$ of $G$, the space of matrix coefficients is a copy of $V \otimes V^$ inside $\mathcal O(G)$ that depends only on the isomorphism type of $V$, and so that it is literally meaningful to write $\mathcal O(G) = \bigoplus_{V \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)} V \otimes V^$.

@LSpice You are correct of course.
